# Unable to assign security group to Bare Metal server in IBM Bluemix

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-cloud-infrastructure, cloud-bare-metal

I have started one bare metal server in IBM Bluemix, the server is Up and Running. But I am unable to open the port, I want allow_all traffic to be enabled on bare metal servers. I can see there are pre-configured security groups, but I am not able to assign those groups to my server.

Any pointers in the right direction will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Generally it’s based on the virtualization technology, so only the virtual servers are eligible to the security groups.
You cannot assign the bare metal servers to the security groups basically, so you have to provision other firewall if you protect those.

https://console.bluemix.net/docs/infrastructure/security-groups/sg_overview.html#about-security-groups

Answer (score 0):

Security groups is only available for Virtual Servers for now. We might in future look into offering security groups for Bare Metal Servers. In the meantime you can use shared hardware firewall to achieve your goal. 
More information about different firewall options 
https://www.ibm.com/blogs/bluemix/2017/09/next-generation-firewall-fortigate-security-appliance-10gbps/